# TFS 2017 web application not displaying well

Tags: tfs

We installed `TFS 2017 update 3` and we are having issues when displaying the icons in the web application. We are having issues with the "`Files`" section inside "`Code`" for each one of our projects, the contents of the files aren't displaying. In the browser `console`, we can see these issues. Our `Bowtie.woff` file has `39KB`.

> CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error. bowtie.eot
>
> CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error. bowtie.woff
>
> CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error. fabricmdl2icons.woff
>
> CSS3114: @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check.
>   Permission must be Installable. fabricmdl2icons.ttf
>
> CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error. fabricmdl2icons.woff
>
> CSS3114: @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check.
>   Permission must be Installable. fabricmdl2icons.ttf

**The request are showing errors:**

> _content/Fonts/Icons/bowtie.eot?iefix                500 internal server error
>
> _content/Fonts/Icons/bowtie.woff                      500 internal server error
>
> _content/Fonts/Icons/bowtie.eot?iefix                500 internal server error
>
> /_scripts/TFS/min/VersionControl/scenarios/Shared/HookSplitterResizeEventToNativeEvent.js
>   500 internal server error
>
> _content/Extensions/CodeEditor/0.8.3/vs/Editor/editor.main.css 500 internal server error
>
> _scripts/Extensions/min/TFS.extension.js     500 internal server error

Comment: What does the EventViewer of the tfs server mention? Usually there is an error logged in the application log for each request that caused an internal server error if it's caused somewhere inside ASP.NET.

Answer (score 2):

I checked the `Bowtie.woff` file on my side, it's also `39KB`. Seems it's not caused by the file.

Seems it's related to the privilege of the service account.

> If you are seeing HTTP 500 when servicing static content, most likely
>   your service account does not have "**Impersonate a client after
>   authentication**" privilege.
>
> Refer to Vladimir's answer in this thread : [TFS 2017 Missing Icons](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f787ef9a-5329-49f2-9f71-c126f15efb11/tfs-2017-missing-icons?forum=tfsgeneral)

To check/add permission you can do the following:

1. Windows **Start** > **Administrative Tools**
2. Open "**Local Security Policy**" editor.
3. Navigate to **Security Settings**  **Local Policies** > **User
   Rights Assignment**
4. Double click on "**Impersonate a client after authentication**"

---

Another possibility is the `web.config` file issue which under below path:

```
 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 15.0\Application Tier\Web Services\_static\tfs\Dev15.M125.1\_content\Fonts
```

Refer to this thred for details : [TFS 2015 Update 2 Missing Icons](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c1038468-9d94-473d-a020-254789e9a19b/tfs-2015-update-2-missing-icons?forum=tfsgeneral)

Comment: **Impersonate a client after authentication** ended up being the issue for our stand alone instance. Thanks Andy!